# Python: Standard Deviation within a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a list of say 50 dataframes 'list1', each dataframe has columns 'Speed' and 'Value', like this;

```
Speed   Value
1       12
2       17
3       19
4       21
5       25
```

I am trying to get the standard deviation of 'Value' for each speed, across all dataframes. The end goal is get a list or df of standard deviation for each speed, like this;

```
Speed   Standard Deviation
1       1.23
2       2.5
3       1.98
4       5.6
5       5.77
```

I've tried to pull the values into a new dataframe using a for loop, to then use 'statistics.stdev' on but I can't seem to get it working. Any help is really appreciatted!

**Update!**

`pd.concat([d.set_index('Speed').values for d in df_power], axis=1).std(1)`

This worked. Although, I forgot to mention that the values for Speed are not always the same between dataframes. Some dataframes miss a few and this ends up returning nan in those instances.

Comment: Please include the attempt which didn’t work. Is using `pandas.concat()` not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `concat` and use `std`:

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
pd.concat([d.set_index('Speed') for d in list_dfs], axis=1).std(1)
```

Comment: OP wrote, he wants the standard deviation for one specific speed across all dataframes

Comment: @Omni **each** not *one specific*.

Comment: @Omni this answer achieves what OP asked for.

Comment: @QuangHoang however, i think you get into trouble if `'Speed'` is not unique within individual dataframes

Comment: I need standard deviation for each speed, however `'values'` is not the only column in the dataframes so `StDev = pd.concat([d.set_index('Speed').values for d in df_power], axis=1).std(1)` is what I ended up using. Although, I should have stated that the values for `Speed` are not always the same. Some dataframes miss a few and this ends up returning nan in those instances. I'll update the question. Thanks @QuangHoang

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to concatenate, groupby speed, and take the standard deviation.

1) Concatenate your dataframes

```
list1 = [df_1, df_2, ...]
full_df = pd.concat(list1, axis=0) # stack all dataframes
```

2) Groupby `speed` and take the standard deviation

```
std_per_speed_df = full_df.groupby('speed')[['value']].std()
```

Comment: `[df for df in list1]` is the same thing as `list1` so just do `pd.concat(list1).groupby('speed').value.std()`

Answer (score 3):

If the dataframes are all saved on the same folder you can use `pd.concat` +`groupby` as already suggested or you can use `dask`

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = dd.read_csv("data/*")
out = df.groupby("Speed")["Value"].std()\
        .compute()\
        .reset_index(name="Standard Deviation")
```